# PHP Automatically increment and save changes in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck with this problem in PHP for a while now, I don't know what is the best way to proceed. 
Let's suppose I have 100 Tapes (named from X0001 until X0100) each one can save up to 50 recording, when I choose a Tape from the 100(through a `checkbox`) and `submit`, it goes to the last inserted element in that tape and automatically names it for me in the DB. To be more explicit, my tape that I chose is X0020 (last element in was tape 03 for example), 03 here is what should be incremented every time, so the next time I choose this tape X0020, it saves some other info (other inputs already made) to tape 04 automatically in the DB.

I am on PHP, I just need to know what is supposed to be done to actually make this happen automatically.

Comment: Add to column id an auto_increment option you will find it named as A_I on phpmyadmin

Comment: I already have the id A_I (but it's the ID of the actual tapes X0000, not the recordings), but then how to say that in PHP ?